# Can't flag or up vote comments on iPad?

Tags: support, comments, ipad

Hey all-

On my iPad with iOS 4.3, I can't up vote or flag comments.  Is this just me?  Or can this get fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, how does it feel to use SO with Ipad :)

Comment: Currently those buttons are attached to mouseover event. Is there mouseover event on iPad, btw?

Comment: It's not so bad, though it's really annoying when autocorrect tries capitalizing code samples or insisting that "dequeue" is not a word. :-)

Comment: Just had this problem too. Its possible but far too difficult. I had to zoom into the controls, click upvote and then zoom out again.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you must

1. touch (tap) the comment first to enable the mouseover (hover) elements
2. touch the voting arrows that appear after you do #1

[image]

At least it has always worked for me that way on the iPhone, or as I like to call it, my iPad Mini. Voted for comments on iPhone many times using that technique.

(and you know about two finger scroll for scrolling divs, right?)

Comment: So I've been trying to do this for a while and the hitbox is really small... It took ten attempts to get this working since you have to click directly on top of the upvote/flag button.  Can you make this easier to use?  And yes, I figured out the div scrolling.  Man was thar counterintuitive...

Comment: @template I just zoom in first using two finger pinch

Comment: For me when there is more than one comment on a page, the first comment  I touch is only 'greyed' while holding the touch, but subsequent touches to other comments enable hovers fine.  So I touch some other comment first...

Comment: That works, but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that.  It's definitely true that tapping once does not show the buttons unless you tap something else first.

Comment: @template I am not sure that is our bug, and I don't recall having to do that in iOS versions < 4.3..

Comment: Fun. Ths is really more iPad suck than SO suck, though. Second only to the absurdity of scrolling divs with iPad.

Comment: Wow Jeff, I like how you called your phone an "iPad Mini". Can you see into the future?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it's fixed now (I have no problem with IPad 2 iOS5).
According to very similar [Voting up comments no longer possible via ipad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109460/voting-up-comments-no-longer-possible-via-ipad?rq=1) it's completed.