# Voting up comments no longer possible via ipad

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ipad

Up until a few days ago, I could vote up comments via my iPad2. Now this is no longer possible, nothing happens when I tap to vote up.

This functionality was previously available, see [Can't flag or up vote comments on iPad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84545/cant-flag-or-up-vote-comments-on-ipad)

Comment: Confirmed, at least on an iPad 2 just updated to ios 5. No amount of clicking anywhere on or near comments brings up the voting flags/widgets.

Comment: Actually, I've found one situation where I *can* get the flags to appear: where a comment contains a link, the first click on the link makes the comment-voting options appear. See the first comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7786882/104370), for example.

Comment: @Clare: thanks for updates. I discovered it on ios 4.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We recently switched from applying different CSS classes in `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to just using `:hover` CSS styles. The former technique goes back to the days when we where still supporting older IEs, which didn't handle `:hover` correctly or at all. Fortunately, that's now in the past.

Mobile Safari is a bit picky about applying `:hover` styles -- apparently it only does that when it's also handling some other click or similar event. In the next build, the comments have a dummy click event handler attached; it well then work as it did before.

This is also why [Clare's workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109460/voting-up-comments-no-longer-possible-via-ipad/109684#109684) works, because interacting with the link is also enough to force the `:hover` styles.

Comment: Could this same technique be used to [get spoiler markup working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75656/149432) in Mobile Safari?

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Excellent idea; that works indeed.

Comment: I see that this has now been rolled out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stringing together the comments above, I've noticed a repeatable workaround for this. The trick is to **click on the hyperlinked name of the commenter**.

This then brings up the little widgets for flagging and up voting comments.