# Unable to copy comments from Stack Overflow in iPad Safari

Tags: bug, comments, ipad, safari

In iPad's [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), when I am opening a Stack Overflow question, I am not able to select/copy text from comments.

There is no similar issues on PC version of Safari.

The possible workaround is to save the page into Pocket, and inside the Pocket Web view I can easily copy any comments text.

I am not sure it is an iPad Safari or Stack Overflow limitation. I am blaming some JavaScript code, that prevents text selection.
Alternatively it could be CSS style (in particular `:hover`) -see [Voting up comments no longer possible via ipad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109460/voting-up-comments-no-longer-possible-via-ipad?rq=1)

Another article about the possible issue of `:hover` processing by iPad Safari can be found at http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/.

Comment: If you hold on the comment long enough, the whole comment will be selected, and you can copy the text. You need to zoom to copy part of the text, though. (Voting up for comment can be done by zooming up a bit)

Comment: @nhahtdh, on my ipad2 ios5 safari,i am not able to select neither whole comment neither part of the textis not sel

Comment: Oh, you need to tap-hold (touch-lift-long touch). Just tested on iPad1. Forgot to mention it is tap-hold.

Comment: @nhahtdh, on my ipad2 ios5 safari I am not able to select neither whole comment, neither part of the comments text, regardless of zooming or time of hold on. (Voting for comment is not a problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I've noticed that I am able to select the whole comment on my iPad2  Safari.

I've upgraded to iOS6 recently. Not sure if Safari changed, or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Probably Safari. I can't select from iOS5, iPad 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof that you cannot copy text from comments, you may be able to select it but the copy popup never appears.

ios9.3

[image: nocopyoption]

Comment: You ha a a different problem - no selection pop up in text of answer. I have similar intermittent issue in Evernote for iPad. But this question was particular about selection of comments.